# Explode php array images

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I work on the user profile & user gallery, i want to show user uploads images and i have problem about it.
I have the following code

```
if($uploads) { $s = explode(",", $uploads); // Explode the images string value
$r=1; $f=count($s); foreach($s as $a) { $newdata=$Mat>Get_Upload_Image_Id($a);
if($newdata) { $final_image=$base_url."uploads/".$newdata['image_path'];
echo '<a aria-haspopup="true" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="Image iLoaded iWithTransition tThumbImage" id="'.$msg_id.'" src="'.$final_image.'"  style="background-image: url('.$final_image.');">
        </div>
        <div class="photoShadow"></div>
        </a>';
}
$r=$r+1; } echo '<span class="snd" style="display:none;" rel="'.$uploads.'">
```

`</span>';
}`

[image: code image]
- This code show me the separately images, i have this code on my HomePage it is ok to separate posts, but on the profile this is not good i wan't the change this, but i'm stuck with this.

I want the show images like this **no separately** in a row:
[image: IMAGE-RESULT]

Comment: paste code here, not image.

Comment: Probably a css problem and not a php one.

Comment: please, recheck your css to full fill your requirement...

Comment: i update @Anant

Comment: @Haris  it's seems css issue not php code issue

Answer (score 1):

put this class in your css and try or if exist the same class with style than update it.

***CSS Class***

```
.iLoaded 
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```